# Generator control over active and reactive power

Tags: generator, three-phase

My background is in electrical installations.  I have been put on a project that is assessing generators. I would like to tap into the experience of those on this forum.

I am asking these questions from the perspective that this is already an established commercial generator.

The generator is "rated" at 30 kVA and 0.8 p.f.. I ASSUME this is a synchronous generator as it can be paralleled with another similar size generator using droop control.

1. Is my assumption correct that it would be a synchronous generator?
2. Does this mean that mean the maximum the generator will produce is 24 kW and 18 kVAr?
3. Can I as the user vary this to generate more kW? Can I run a 30 kVA load at 0.9 p.f. so I could draw 27 kW and 13 kVAr?
4. Can you recommend a resource that can give me a good overview of operating characteristics of generators?

Comment: Are you looking at this from a complete engine+generator or only the generator part?

Comment: Just trying to understand what the alternator can produce. Want to know if I can pull more kW out of it for the same kVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can parallel them with droop they are synchronous.
Generator ratings are basically derived from the current rating and isolation class which determines the maximum voltage. Based on this a generator gets a kVA rating. There is de-rating based on temperature an duty cycle.

For example, a backup generator has a higher rating than a marine generator because of their duty cycle and expected loads.

There are limiting factors on the excitation system, this prevents the generator from operating with negative kVAr (capacitive)

All these parameters determine the [capability curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability_curve).

Notice there is nothing about kW yet. This is not a rating of the generator, this is a rating of the engine, and only the engine.
*You can max out on kVAr by running 0 pf into a loadbank, convert 0 kW (some losses) and remain within specs of the generator. The engine barely notices.*

Today, in modern times, there are more factors at play, for example: if you have many non-linear loads (frequency drives or PCs) you need to oversize the generator because of additional heating of the windings from [harmonic currents](https://www.stamford-avk.com/sites/stamfordavk/files/AGN025_B.pdf). This reduces the effective rating of the generator, such that if you want to have 10 kW of non-linear loads you may need a 25 kVA generator.

So to answer 3, can the user change this to get more kW? No, kW are an engine rating but you can decrease it if you have the wrong load.

Generator vendors publish information. Such as [Stamford](https://www.stamford-avk.com/downloads/agn), [Mecc-alte](https://www.meccalte.com/en/download-area).